# ip rule show command doesn't work

Tags: ip, iproute2

While executing `ip rule show` the command gives the following error

```
# ip rule show
RTNETLINK answers: Address family not supported by protocol
Dump terminated
```

How do I fix this issue. Is there any kernel module need to be added.

Thanks
~S

Comment: Which distro, version and kernel version are you running?

Comment: This is a custom build linux based on debian and kernel version is 4.13

Comment: and my ip version is  \n ~ # ip -V
ip utility, iproute2-ss170905

Comment: Any help on this would be appreciated .. I am a kind of stuck :-(